# Correct Syntax for Filename Statement using a dataset variable

Tags: sas, filenames

I'm a SAS newbie and I don't seem to be able to work out the correct syntax for this. I have a dataset (fileList) with one field (projFile) which holds a filename. I wish to open the file and read the contents into a second field that will be created. The file is zipped (it's a SAS-EG project file) and so I'm told that I should use ***Filename*** statement with the ***zip*** option to read the file. However, no matter how I reference ***projFile*** it doesn't like it.

```
data fileList;
set fileList;
    filename inzip zip "&projFile" member="project.xml";
    infile inzip;
    input fileContent $char2000.;
    output;
run;
```

I may also have the input statement wrong, but until I can get past this issue, I don't know. Thanks.

Comment: Do you also need to read the xml file in a data-wise way via the `LIBNAME` xml engine ?

Answer (score 4):

If you are always reading the same file (member) from the ZIP file you can use the FILEVAR= option on the infile statement to switch which ZIP file you are reading that member from.

So if I have three ZIP files that each has a file named example.txt in it and a dataset like this with the list of filenames.

```
data fnames ;
  input filename $80.;
cards;
c:\downloads\file1.zip
c:\downloads\file2.zip
c:\downloads\file3.zip
;
```

Then I can use that dataset to drive the creation of a new dataset that has the information from those files.

```
data test;
  set fnames ;
  fname=filename;
  infile in zip filevar=fname member='example.txt' end=eof truncover;
  do while (not eof);
    input line $100. ;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

If the driving dataset has the list of members in the ZIP file to read then you can use the MEMVAR= option on the INFILE statement also.

```
data members ;
  infile cards dsd dlm='|' truncover ;
  input filename :$80. memname :$80.;
cards;
c:\downloads\file1.zip|example.txt
c:\downloads\file2.zip|example.txt
c:\downloads\file3.zip|example.txt
;

data test;
  set members ;
  filevar=filename;
  memvar=memname;
  infile in zip filevar=filevar memvar=memvar end=eof truncover;
  do while (not eof);
    input line $100. ;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Hmm, didn't know `filevar` could work with zip files - good to know it does!

Comment: @Joe Works with pretty much all engines.  PIPE, FTP, SFTP, etc.

Comment: It doesn't work on "aggregate" filenames - like ZIP for example - and I figured FTP was similar, but glad to learn it wasn't!

Comment: This answer is demonstrating it working on ZIP engine. You can use MEMVAR= with or without FILEVAR=.  You can even use MEMVAR= with a multiple directory aggregate fileref.  `filename agg ("&dir\test1" "&dir\test2"); ...  infile agg memvar=memname end=eof ;`  Note normal rules for which version is used if the same member appears in multiple places.

Comment: Hmm, I'm going to have to go back and look at what caused me to get that error - that wording is directly from SAS's error message answering another question.

Comment: I can't replicate what I was getting, so must've been doing something else wrong - works fine for me now, anyway.  TIL :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a few issues here.

First - you probably shouldn't use `data filelist; set filelist;` if you're doing something like this.  Make a new dataset.

Second - `filename` is not executable.  It is declarative.  You *can* place it inside the data step, but you shouldn't, and for precisely this reason: it makes you think it's doing something inside the data step.  It's not.  It's doing something, period, and then the data step happens, later (even when placed here).

Third - you aren't using `infile` properly, but that's really a consequence of Second.  You need the `filevar` option on `infile` to allow it to do something different here.

Fourth - you probably don't really want to just read arbitrarily from the `project.xml`.  Really this whole thing is probably not what you want to do... I've done what you're doing, and it's doable, but not *this* way.  But that's probably a bigger question.

If this were to work, what you'd do is this:

```
filename a zip "c:\doesntmatter.egp" member="project.xml";

data files;
  length fname $255;
  infile datalines truncover;
  input @1 fname $255.;
datalines;
c:\myfile.egp
c:\myfile2.egp
c:\myfile3.egp
;;;;
run;

data egp;
  set files;
  infile a filevar=fname pad truncover;
  input @1 first_line $512. @;
  put first_line;
run;
```

The `filename` statement doesn't really do anything, but I show you where it would go.  You see the `filevar` on the infile statement - that points to the `fname` variable on `files`.  Then it reads in from there.

My general suggestion is that you should probably use the `xml` libname engine here; figure out what you want to do on a per-xml basis, write that out as a macro, then call the macro for each line in the file name dataset (using `call execute` probably, or if you must, `dosubl`).  You don't *have* to use the `xml` libname engine, but it'll simplify things most likely.

If you're only using *one* file, then you can specify it directly in the `filename` statement I showed above, and just use `infile` with that filename (`infile a;` here, but please call it something more sensible than `a`).  But again, it's silly to read it in this way - use the libname engine, as it'll parse out the xml for you.

---

Edits, to remove incorrect information confirmed by Tom's answer.  Even though it does work, I don't recommend using `infile` here - read it with the libname engine, it'll save you loads of time.

Comment: Thanks. Info greatly appreciated.